# Support for HTTP multipart response in Netty?

Tags: netty, multipart, multipartentity, multipartform-data

I would like to know if there are any way to send multipart responses to a client.

Is there some way I could attach multiple images to one response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContent just works with ByteBuf... so its up to you to convert the content to ByteBuf.